# Detener la ejecución al lanzar un Activity

Tags: android, activity

Yo programaba en *C#*, en *Windows*, pero ahora estoy desarrollando en *Android*:

Quiero lanzar un *Activity*, ya conozco cómo lanzarlo con `INTENTS`, `StartCativity(typeof(ActivityALanzar))`, y `StartActityForResult()`, pero la ejecución continúa, es decir que al lanzar el *Activity*, se lanza en otro hilo.

Yo quiero algo como como lo existe en los formularios ***.Net*** (`form.ShowDialog()`), que el *Activity* se lance en el mismo hilo y que el ***Activity padre*** se quede esperando que el ***Activity hijo*** cierre.

Ya intenté deteniendo el hilo principal pero esto colapsa la *App*.

¿Cómo puedo resolver esto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que buscas es un [`DialogFragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) que se muestra encima de tu activity y no que se abra otra vista.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para esto tienes que crear una clase que herede de `DialogFragment`. Por ejemplo:

```
public class MiFormularioDialogo extends DialogFragment
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_de_tu_activity, container, false);

        // buscamos los elementos de la vista para asignar asignarles eventos a estos
        Button button = (Button)layout.findViewById(R.id.show);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
              // evento click del button
            }
        });

        return layout; // retornamos la vista
    }
}
```

En la parte donde esta `inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_de_tu_activity, container, false);` tienes que reemplazar `layout_de_tu_activity` por el nombre del layout de la actividad que quieres que se muestre. Utiliza la variable `layout` para asignar los eventos a las vistas del dialogo.

Entonces para mostrarlo utilizas el `getFragmentManager()`:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

ft.addToBackStack(null);

// Inicializamos el dialogo y lo mostramos
DialogFragment newFragment = new MiFormularioDialogo()
newFragment.show(ft, "dialog");
```